# Jquery split by option tags

Tags: php, jquery, html, arrays

I'm trying to grab the text from options in a dropdown list. Assume that the following dropdown has hundreds of options.

```
<select name="colors" id="colors">
    <option value="744">Green</option>
    <option value="933">Red</option>
    <option value="1838">Yellow</option>
    <option value="1839">Blue</option>
</select>
```

I want to output the text from all options in an array format that I'll be able to copy and paste in php. Example:

```
'Green', 'Red', 'Yellow', 'Blue'
```

This is what I have

```
var optionText = $("option").text().split().join(", ");
$('.gettext').append(optionText);
```

I'm not sure how to split by `</option>` tags and add single quotes around each option item.

http://jsfiddle.net/tp74c/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/gion_13/tp74c/1/

Iterate through each option and push its text into an array.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest turning the options into an array a different way before joining them, using `map`:

```
var optionText = $('option').map(function() {
    return $(this).text();
}).get().join(', ');
```

You can also add the quotes this way, like so:

```
var optionText = $('option').map(function() {
    return "'" + $(this).text() + "'";
}).get().join(', ');
```

Edit: As alex points out, this doesn't work, which is odd, because I tested it somewhere. Fixed now.

Comment: I think you'd need to use `get()` on the returned set first. jQuery doesn't have a `join()` method.

Comment: @alex: I'm not much of a jQuery person, I just test everything on Stack Overflow and it appears to work, so... :) I'll add that, thanks.